# Random exam generator

Tags: javascript, beginner

I've written a short Random Exam Generator program.
There are 6 days, 3 time slots per day. One day can not have more than 2 exams. There will be 5 exams in total.

I am fairly new to programming so I would like some feedback on how well this code is written, and if there are any ways to improve it.

```
var exam_days = 
    { 0: 0, 
      1: 0, 
      2: 0, 
      3: 0, 
      4: 0, 
      5: 0 };

var exam_array = []; 

function generateSchedule() {
  for (var i = 0; exam_array.length < 5; i++){
    var time = getRandomInt(0,2);
    var day = getRandomInt(0,5);
    var exam_id = "exam-" + time + day; 
    if (dayAvailable(day, exam_days) && uniqueExam(exam_id, exam_array)) {
      exam_days[day] += 1; 
      exam_array.push(exam_id); 
      document.getElementById(exam_id).style.background = "green"; 
    }
  }  
}

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function dayAvailable(date, exam_days) {

  if (exam_days[date] < 2) {
      return true;
    }
  return false;   
}

function uniqueExam(exam, exam_array)
{
    var count = exam_array.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        if (exam_array[i] === exam) 
          return false;
    }
    return true; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Library functions usage

The `unique_exam` function is basically checking if the exam is in the array or not and returning false if it is not, the `includes` method is what You need.

`return ! exam_array`[`.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)`(exam)`

#### Inline

```
dayAvailable
```

Should be inlined as it boils down to just one comparison, instead the number of exams per day should be saved as a constant.